# conditionally send props to child element Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-props

I wanna send props to **Quantity** component conditionally with this example.

```
<v-card
 class="mx-auto"
 max-width="344"
 shaped
 v-for="(item, index) in allItems || orderedItems"
 :key="index"
>

<Quantity {allItems ? :Items = item : :Ordered = item} />

</v-card>
```

I want to send *Ordered* props if `orderedItems` is Activated and send `Items` if `allItems` is activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `v-bind` instead:

```
<Quantity v-bind="quantityProps" />
```

Then create a method for this:

```
quantityProps(item) {
  return {
    [this.allItems ? 'Items' : 'Ordered']: item
  }
}
```